# Finding Key Mgmt Service (KMS) Client Machine ID (CMID) on Windows XP SP3 or Win7

Tags: windows-xp, windows-7, licensing

How do I find the Client Machine ID (CMID) of a Windows XP SP3 or a Win7 PC, that it is using to identify itself against a MS Key Management Service (KMS) Host?

The CMID can be found on a Vista client by running *slmgr /dli*, according to http://support.microsoft.com/kb/929829/en-us (note there is a typo in the KB article, it specifies a dash not a slash for the dli switch). However, *slmgr* will not run on WinXP and on Win7 it does not return the CMID, from what I can see. I don't have a Vista client on which to test.

As *slmgr -rearm* is not going to work on WinXP, is there another way to reset the CMID on WinXP, should I need to?

Answer (score 1):

Based on this [article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc303277.aspx), it appears that the KMS server is only used in Vista, Server 2008, and later, so not Windows XP.

This [article](http://blogs.technet.com/hectorl/archive/2009/07/20/windows-7-and-windows-server-2008-r2-volume-activation-deployment-guide-published.aspx) has information about KMS on Windows 7 and Server 2008 R2.

Answer (score 1):

Windows XP does not make use of KMS.